# My app is only shown if I search it with underscores instead of spaces in Google PlayStore search

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

My app was published 5 days ago on the Google Play Store. My app has a unique name and I can´t find the app when I search for the exact name of the app even if I scroll down to the end. It is curious because I can find the app if I type the name of the app but using underscores instead of spaces. For example: If I search "My app name" it doesn´t appear, but, if I search: "My_app_name" it appears. Why it only appears if I search it with underscores? Also if I type: "My developer name" it doesn´t appear, but, if I type "My_developer_name" it does. What is the mystery of the underscore? I don´t understand anything...